# WSGI/Nginx/Internal server error arises when I deactivate virtual environment (no python application found)

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi, wsgi

I'm stuck with this error. 
-— no python application found, check your startup logs for errors —-
Internal server error.

Whenever I'm in virtual environment all works fine but If I deactivate virtualenv I'm constantly getting this error each time when I send a GET query to my webpage.
So because of this problem Im getting this error in supervisor mode.

I have tested this outside of supervisor mode using this command:
uwsgi —ini my_site_uwsgi.ini
And like I said before It works fine when I'm in virtualenv and It raises error listed above error when I deactivate virtualenv.

```
#codepaint_news_uwsgi.ini
[uwsgi]

chdir = /home/django/codepaint
module = codepaint.wsgi
home = /home/django/venv
master = true
processes = 10
socket = /home/django/codepaint/uwsgi_nginx.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
env = DEBUG_MODE=False
_____________________________________
#wsgi.py

import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "codepaint.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
______________________________________
```

Internal server error.
-— no python application found, check your startup logs for errors —-

Comment: Maybe it's referring to python executable

Answer (score 0):

Compare the installed apps in your venv to the ones in your non venv (global python).